# Getting clicked file's name in an exe application

Tags: windows, input, arguments, exe

I created an exe application which I want to have as a default program for special file types. Currently I run the program from cmd as follows: "myapp.exe filename" and I got the file from argv. I set myapp.exe to be the default application and double clicked the file. What happened is that myapp.exe was ran without the file as input.

How do I get the file that was double clicked and ran the exe?

Comment: I wrote it in python and converted to exe

Comment: you might want to check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx